# From CURSOR to a SET based approach utilizing a temp table with no IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a `CURSOR` that loops through a temporary table that contains the paths to  hundreds of various .txt files that need to be `BULK INSERT` into a `Persons` table. The temporary table is also established from a single .txt file that has no identity columns. The FileList.txt text file looks like the following:

```
...
E:\Dept1\Type1\2005.txt
E:\Dept1\Type1\2006.txt
E:\Dept1\Type1\2007.txt
E:\Dept2\Type1\2005.txt
E:\Dept2\Type1\2006.txt
...
```

I'm loading the FileList.txt into a temporary table with a `BULK INSERT`. Given this, the only column in the temporary table is the `Path` column. If I had an additional identity column, the `BULK INSERT` would fail due to there being as mismatch of column numbers.

I want to fine tune this to use a `WHILE` loop. However, I've hit a bit of a dead brain on how best to utilize one. Every solution that uses a`WHILE` loop that I've seen assumes that a sequential identity column exists. My current query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #NAMES_filelist (Path VARCHAR(MAX))
BULK INSERT #NAMES_filelist FROM 'E:\FileList.txt' WITH 
    ( 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
DECLARE @FILEPATH VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLBULK VARCHAR(MAX)
-- Beginning the cursor to loop through the file list.
DECLARE C1 CURSOR
FOR SELECT Path FROM #NAMES_filelist
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @FILEPATH
WHILE
    @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN
       -- Setting @SQLBULK to do the bulk insert of the index files.
       SET @SQLBULK = 
       -- Utilizing a view due to additional columns in dbo.Persons in comparison to the index file.
       'BULK INSERT Persons_view FROM ''' + @FILEPATH + ''' WITH 
          ( 
           MAXERRORS = 0
          ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|''
          ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
          )'
       EXEC (@SQLBULK)
       -- Updating the DEPT and INDEXFILE columns for lookup purposes.
       UPDATE
          Persons
       SET
          DEPT = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@FILEPATH), CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FILEPATH)) + 1, CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FILEPATH), CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FILEPATH)) + 1) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@FILEPATH)) - 1))
          ,INDEXFILE = REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@FILEPATH),CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@FILEPATH), 1) - 1))
       WHERE
          DEPT IS NULL
          AND INDEXFILE IS NULL
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @FILEPATH
    END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
DROP TABLE #NAMES_filelist
```

Any fresh ideas you guys have would be incredibly useful.

Comment: There's literally no gain in changing this from a cursor to a `WHILE` loop

Comment: I should have clarified that I want to change it to better learn how to utilize `WHILE` loops. I don't particularly need to change it, but I've been having a hard time grasping how to use `WHILE` loops and I'm simply practicing to expand my knowledge. @Lamak

Comment: Then the easiest way would be to add an identity column to your `#NAMES_filelist` table and the use the `WHILE` loop as you want

Comment: As mentioned above, adding an identity column to the temporary table causes the initial `BULK INSERT` to break since there is a mismatch of columns. @Lamak

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk insert into a view.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES_filelist (
    NAMES_filelist int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    Path VARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE VIEW v_NAMES_filelist as
    select NAMES_filelist
    from NAMES_filelist;

BULK INSERT  v_NAMES_filelist FROM 'E:\FileList.txt' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

That said, the cursor is a fine approach.  But, this will give you an automatically incrementing id in the table of file names.